# Разница между шестнадцатеричными литералами

Tags: java, c++, c, hex

Какая разница между `0x0` и `0x00`? 
Какая разница между `0xF` и `0xFFFFFFFF`? 
Эти значения занимают разное количество памяти? 
Как научиться правильно читать и понимать, а так же пользоваться шестнадцатеричной системой счисления? 
На моем проекте очень много работы с битовыми масками и иногда я не понимаю, как люди выбирают, как и что им записывать? Почему иногда это `0xF`, а иногда `0xFF`. 
Прочитал уже достаточно материалов по тому, как именно это работает, но все равно не понимаю, как **правильно** научиться использовать битовые флаги и понимать, что выбирать и какая между этими выборами разница.

Пример из библиотеки `OpenGL`:

```
#define GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT               0x00000100
#define GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT             0x00000400
```

Не могу понять, почему эти два флага разные? Думал, все зависит от того, на какой позиции стоит бит.

Comment: Укажите язык программирования.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow C++

Comment: Литералы ничего не значат, это просто удобный для программиста способ представления данных в коде, а что и как хранится в памяти — зависит от используемого вами типа данных

Comment: `#define` из вашего примера тем более ничего не значит, потому что неиспользуемые define'ы в готовую программу не попадают вообще никак, а хранение используемых зависит от того, где и как и в каком контексте они используются

Comment: Если использовать их в OpenGL-функции `glClear`, то там используется  тип GLbitfield, который, [если верить вики](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Type), занимает 32 бита (4 байта)

Comment: Манипуляции с битовыми флагами никак не зависят от того, в каком виде вы записываете литералы. Просто изучите, как работают побитовые операции, а с какими литералами в какой системе счисления их делать — совершенно неважно, результат будет один и тот же в любом случае

Comment: *Не могу понять, почему эти два флага разные? Думал, все зависит от того, на какой позиции стоит бит.* У GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT установлен 17-й бит, у GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT - 19-й. Если считать от младших битов. и самый младший считать первым, есссно...

Comment: Между 0xF и 0xFF разница такая же, как между 9 и 99.

Comment: *"Какая разница между 0xF и 0xFFFFFFFF? Эти значения занимают разное количество памяти?"* А ведь самое забавное - что таки да, разное - как *литерал в исходнике*, первый занимает 3 байта, а второй - 10 байт...

Comment: @Harry а почему 3 байта?

Comment: Потому что даже в UTF-8 (вряд ли кодировка исходника отлична от windows-1251 или UTF-8) в исходнике три ASCII-символа занимают три байта... Еще раз перечитайте - я писал *"как литерал в исходнике"*.

Comment: @Harry аа, понял. спасибо.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Так как вы не указали конкретный язык программирования, а в вашем профиле чаще фигурирует язык Java, то я в своем ответе буду иметь в виду именно Java.

Целочисленные литералы, если они не имеют суффикс `L` (или `l`) имеют тип `int`, то есть занимают в памяти 4 байта.

Поэтому не важно, какое значение имеет целочисленный шестнадцатиричный литерал либо `0xF`, либо `0xFFFFFFFF`, он будет занимать `4` байта, то есть иметь один и тот же размер занимаемой памяти.

С другой стороны, очевидно, что эти два целочисленных литерала, приведенных в качестве примера. имеют разные значения.

Также очевидно, что эти два целочисленных шестнадцатиричных литерала `0x0` и `0x00` имеют одно и то же значение, то есть 0.

(**Примечание**. Интересно отметить, что хотя данные два целочисленных литерала, `0` и `00`, в Java имеют одно и то же значение. то есть ноль, тем не менее первый целочисленный литерал считается десятичным целочисленным литералом. а второй целочисленный литерал является восьмиричным целочисленным литералом.)

Обычно шестнадцатиричные литералы удобно использовать в битовых операциях по выделению отдельных битов числа или проверки установки битов.

Например, этот литерал `0xF` можно использовать для выделения четырех битов некоторого числа, а этот литерал `0xFF` удобно использовать для выделения младшего байта числа.

Например,

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int x = 0x12_34_56_78;

        System.out.println( "x & 0xF = " + ( x & 0xF ) );
        System.out.println( "x & 0xFF = " + ( x & 0xFF ) );
    }
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
x & 0xF = 8
x & 0xFF = 120
```

**Правка:**

В C++ для суффиксов целочисленных литералов имеется больше значений. Могут использоваться следующие суффиксы: `U(u), L(l) и LL(ll)` и комбинация последних двух суффиксов с суффиксом `U(u)`.

То есть в C++ большее разнообразие целочисленных типов.

Конкретный целочисленный тип шестнадцатиричного литерала без суффикса определяется его значением. То есть выбирается первый тип, который может содержать значение заданного шестнадцатиричного литерала.

```
int 
unsigned int
long int
unsigned long int
long long int
unsigned long long int
```

Вот пример демонстрационной программы на C (которая может быть, фактически совершенно без изменений переписана на C++), которая показывает некоторые битовые операции с шестнадцатиричными литералами.

В программе определена функция, которая записывает значение числа в обратном порядке.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

unsigned int reverse_nibbles( unsigned int x ) 
{ 
    unsigned int y = 0; 

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 2 * sizeof( unsigned int ); i++ ) 
    { 
        y <<= 4; 
        y |= x & 0xF; 
        x >>= 4; 
    } 

    return y; 
} 

int main(void)  
{ 
    unsigned int x = 0x12345678; 
    unsigned int y = reverse_nibbles( x ); 

    printf( "%x\t%x\n", x , y ); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
12345678    87654321
```

Иногда вместо шестнадцатиричного литерала удобнее использовать двоичгый литерал, который может выглядеть более наглядно.

Например, шестнадцатиричный литерал `0x3` может быть переписан как двоичный литерал `0b11`, где более наглядно видно, что два младших бита установлены в 1.

Что касается вашего вопроса относительно этих флагов

```
#define GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT               0x00000100
#define GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT             0x00000400
```

то вам просто следует прочитать документацию OpenGl, где они описаны.

Comment: "литерал 0xFF удобно использовать для выделения младшего бита числа" - вы, наверное, хотели написать "байта"

Comment: @aa_talanin Да, это была опечатка.

Comment: понял. но тогда такой вопрос. если мы хотим указать маску которая занимает два бита, это корректная маска? Или надо выбирать такие, чтобы они занимали именно один бит? Пример: `0x09`. Правильно использовать такое значение как маску?

Comment: @raviga Вы можете указать маску с любым количеством установленных в 1 бит, которая умещается в заданном типе. Например, 0x3 (два младших бита установлены), Или для этих целей можно использовать двоичный литерал 0B11

Comment: @raviga зависит от того, какая задача стоит. Если вам нужно включать или выделять эти два бита, то правильно, а если не нужно, то неправильно :)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ааааааааааа. я понял. к примеру в RGBA мы можем сразу переключать 4 бита и это будет каким-то результатирующим цветом. правильно?

Comment: @raviga Да, можно использовать битовые операторы и шестнадцатиричные (или двоичные) литералы для установки цвета.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow не очень понимаю момент с `reverse_nibble`. Можем перейти в приватный чат и поговорить об этом?

Comment: @raviga Я не принимаю участие в чатах. Попробуйте разобраться с функцией самостоятельно шаг за шагом, например, вставив дополнительную печать переменных в цикле.,